# Java C3P0 Resource Starving

Tags: java, sql-server, multithreading, c3p0, starvation

I have been looking at an issue where a main workflow table with a relevant dao (which is hit lots by multiple threads) is struggling to keep up with requests in a fair way - almost like resource starvation.

The threads all are responsible for pulling data (around 5 of them) from various external  systems.

The issue here is that when a thread gets so much information at once - it hammers requests to the table which leaves the others competing for access / resource. As such, typically they time out and need to be restarted.

Are there any mechanisms or strategies to manage this kind of thing. I was thinking off the top of my head (this is my first initial thought) to create some form of blocking list which all the threads can add too (on a first come first served basis maybe) and then filter through the SimpleJdbcOperations that way.

I would be open to any theories for solving such a problem that are considered standard for this kind of problem.

Thanks

Comment: Are threads just reading data from the table or are they also writing?

Comment: They are also writing - via various methods in the DAO